# Como salvar globalmente o output de uma função no R?

Tags: r, programação-funcional

Tenho problemas para salvar a saída de funções no R. No código a seguir, por exemplo, crio uma matriz que representa um jogo de sudoku:

```
quantLinhas <- readline(prompt = 'insira o número de linhas do sudoku: ') #para saber a dimensão do sudoku
quantLinhas <- as.numeric(quantLinhas) #readline salva como string, transferindo para numérico


construcaoSudoku <- function(){
  matrizSudoku <- NA   #atribuindo NA para o rbind funcionar corretamente
  
  for(i in seq(1, quantLinhas)){
    linhaEntrada <- scan()
    matrizSudoku <- rbind(matrizSudoku, linhaEntrada) 
  }
  matrizSudoku <- matrizSudoku[-1,]    #retirando a primeira linha, composta por NAs
  sudoku <- return(matrizSudoku)
}
```

reparem na última linha, onde tento retornar a `matrizSudoku` e salvá-la na variável `sudoku`.
Acontece que não funciona, ao que parece, a variável `sudoku` é gerada localmente, mas não globalmente. Preciso dela salva globalmente pois será usada mais a frente por outra função

Comment: Aparentemente, depois de criada a função, eu posso rodar ela atribuindo-a a uma variável, desta forma: `sudoku <- construcaoSudoku()`
Mas não há como fazer isso dentro da própria função?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O princípio a seguir é este:

> Em R as funções retornam o **resultado da última instrução**.

Então, para retornar uma variável, basta pô-la sózinha na última instrução.

```
construcaoSudoku <- function(){
  matrizSudoku <- NA   #atribuindo NA para o rbind funcionar corretamente
  
  for(i in seq(1, quantLinhas)){
    linhaEntrada <- scan()
    matrizSudoku <- rbind(matrizSudoku, linhaEntrada) 
  }
  matrizSudoku <- matrizSudoku[-1,]    #retirando a primeira linha, composta por NAs
  matrizSudoku
}
```

Também podia ser `return(matrizSudoku)` mas a função `return` não é necessária neste caso.

Para atribuir o resultado da função no `.GlobalEnv` é fácil. Basta atribuir o **resultado da função**, não dentro da função.

```
sudoku <- construcaoSudoku()
```

Finalmente, isto responde à pergunta tal como foi colocada. Mas eu não utilizaria uma variável, `quantLinhas` definida fora da função e que não é passada como argumento. Creio que isto é má prática, a evitar se possível.

A função ficaria melhor com um argumento:

```
construcaoSudoku <- function(n){
  matrizSudoku <- NA   #atribuindo NA para o rbind funcionar corretamente

  for(i in seq_len(n)){
    linhaEntrada <- scan()
    matrizSudoku <- rbind(matrizSudoku, linhaEntrada) 
  }
  matrizSudoku <- matrizSudoku[-1,]    #retirando a primeira linha, composta por NAs
  matrizSudoku
}

sudoku <- construcaoSudoku(quantLinhas)
```

Uma função equivalente, mas mais simples, é a versão abaixo, com um ciclo `replicate`.

```
construcaoSudoku2 <- function(n){
  matrizSudoku <- t(replicate(n, scan()))
  matrizSudoku
}

sudoku2 <- construcaoSudoku2(quantLinhas)
```

Ou até, numa única linha de código,

```
construcaoSudoku3 <- function(n) t(replicate(n, scan()))
```